# How to search graph database using Python?

Tags: python, pydantic, memgraphdb

I want to search graphs inside Python without the burden of having to learn a new query language. I extensively use `pydantic` library and I wonder if the two can work together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [GQLAlchemy](https://memgraph.com/gqlalchemy). It is an open source object graph mapper, and it is created using the pydantic library. You can check the implementation at [GiHub repo](https://github.com/memgraph/gqlalchemy).

GQLAlchemy lets you connect with Memgraph more easily and helps you if you’re not familiar with Cypher query language.

Here is an example of how to [build a robust app with GQLAlchemy](https://memgraph.com/blog/building-robust-applications-using-gqlalchemy).